# Recreate the strstr() function

Tags: c, pointers, strstr

Hello i am trying to make my own `strstr()` function and i can't figure out why it is returning a segmentation fault.I am trying to search a string within another string and then return a pointer to the first 'same' letter. Any help would be appreciated.
This is my code:

```
char* ms_search(char *Str1,char* Str2){
    char* p = NULL;
    int i,k=0,j = 0;
    for(i = 0;i < ms_length(Str1); i++){
        if(Str1[i] == Str2[k]){
            if(k == 0){
                p = &Str1[i];
                j= i;
            }
            if(k == ms_length(Str2)){
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        else{
            if(Str1[i] == Str2[0]){
                p = &Str1[i];
                k=1;
                j= i;
            }   
            else{
                j=0;
                k = 0;
                p = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
    if(p != NULL){
        Str1[ms_length(Str2)+1] = '\0';
    }
    return &Str1[j];
} 
int main(){
    int i;
    char* p2;
    char* p="lolaaa";
    char* p1= "aaa";
    //char ar2[] = "aaa4";
    //ms_copy(p,p1);
    //printf("%s",p);
    //ms_nconcat(p,p1,3);
    //if(ms_ncompare(p,p1,3) == 1) printf("einai idia");
    p2 = ms_search(p,p1);
    printf("%s",p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run it in the debugger, and step through? What do you see when you load the core file in the debugger, and examine the stack trace and variables?

Comment: Original `strstr()` function will NOT change the passed buffer. Trying to modify string literal invokes *undefined behavior*. Please describe what you want to do.

Comment: @Μιχάλης The function is too complicated. As any complicated function it has bugs.:)

Comment: @Μιχάλης Also you may not change string literals.

Comment: What could i use in order to avoid "Str1[ms_length(Str2)+1] = '\0';", which changes the string literals? Also i would like to mention that the same code worked when i used arrays as the input value to the function.

Comment: @Μιχάλης As you wrote yourself you should "Recreate the strstr() function".:)

Comment: What is `ms_lengt()`?

Comment: `strstr()` uses signature `char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);`.  I recommend your code does the same.

Comment: "What could i use in order to avoid "Str1[ms_length(Str2)+1] = '\0';"," --> Easy.  Delete that line.  To replicate `strstr()` that null character assignment is not needed.

Comment: `printf("%s",p2);` --> `if (p2) printf("%.*s",(int) strlen(p1), p2);` to print a character array up to a _null character_ or up to a certain width.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 5):

> Hello i am trying to make my own strstr()

First of all you have to follow the C standard.

The C89/C99 prototype is:

```
char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
```

Standard `strstr()` function will NOT change the passed buffers.

The functionality is described as:

`strstr()` function locates the ﬁrst occurrence in the string pointed to by `s1` of the sequence of characters (excluding the terminating null character) in the string pointed to by `s2.`

The `strstr` function returns a pointer to the located string, or a null pointer if the string is not found. If `s2` points to a string with zero length, the function returns `s1`.

In standard C, this can be implemented as:

```
#include <string.h> /* size_t memcmp() strlen() */
char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t n = strlen(s2);
    while(*s1)
        if(!memcmp(s1++,s2,n))
            return (char *) (s1-1);
    return 0;
}
```

The standalone implementation is given below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *strstr1(const char *str, const char *substring)
{
    const char *a;
    const char *b;

    b = substring;

    if (*b == 0) {
        return (char *) str;
    }

    for ( ; *str != 0; str += 1) {
        if (*str != *b) {
            continue;
        }

        a = str;
        while (1) {
            if (*b == 0) {
                return (char *) str;
            }
            if (*a++ != *b++) {
                break;
            }
        }
        b = substring;
    }

    return NULL;
}

int main (void)
{
  char string[64] ="This is a test string for testing strstr";
  char *p;

  p = strstr1 (string,"test");

  if(p)
  {
    printf("String found:\n" );

    printf ("First occurrence of string \"test\" in \"%s\" is:\n%s", string, p);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("String not found!\n" );
  }

  return 0; 
}
```

Output:

```
String found:
First occurrence of string "test" in "This is a test string for testing strstr" is:
test string for testing strstr
```

Answer (score 0):

Your standalone strstrl is correct.
I have my preferences, and you have yours.
Neither is perfect.
You prefer

```
if ( *b == 0 ) {
    return (char *) s1;
}
```

I prefer

```
 if ( ! *b ) return (char *) s1;
```

You prefer

```
str += 1;
```

I prefer

```
str++;
```

You prefer

```
while (1)
```

I prefer

```
for (;;)
```

If I rewrite your strstrl with my preferences, we get

```
char *strstr1(const char *str, const char *substring)
{
  const char *a, *b = substring;

  if ( !*b ) return (char *) str;
  for ( ; *str ; str++) {
    if (*str != *b) continue;
    a = str;
    for (;;) {
      if ( !*b ) return (char *) str;
      if (*a++ != *b++) break;
    }
    b = substring;
  }
  return NULL;
}
```

Note that this version has the same snippet

```
if ( ! *b ) return (char *) str;
```

in two locations.  Can we rearrange to do that test only once?

Note how we do two tests when lead character matches

```
if ( *str != *b )
```

and again later for the same lead char

```
a = str ; if ( *a++ != *b++)
```

Can we rearrange that to do a single test?

My rewrite of your standalone strstr is below.  It might not be
your style, but it is in many ways similar to your standalone strstr.
My rewrite is shorter and, I want to believe, easier to understand.

```
char *strstr(const char *str, const char *substring)
{
  const char *a = str, *b = substring;
  for (;;) {
    if ( !*b ) return (char *) str;
    if ( !*a ) return NULL;
    if ( *a++ != *b++) { a = ++str; b = substring; }
  }
}
```