# Return a pointer to the first appearance of a word appearing inside a given C-string

Tags: c++, pointers, c-strings

I have been having a problem figuring out how to return a pointer point to the first character of the word in the given C-string. Here is what the problem says: Write the function findFirst(). The function has two parameters: a const char * s1 pointing to the first character in a C-style string, and a const char * s2. Return a pointer to the first appearance of s2 appearing inside s1 and nullptr (0) if s2 does not appear inside s.

Here is my code:

```
#include <cstddef>  // size_t for sizes and indexes
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const char* findFirst(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while (*s1)     // go through each element in s1
    {
      ++s1;
        if (*s1 == *s2)
        {
          while(*s2)
          {
            ++s1;
            ++s2;
            if (*s1 == *s2 && *s2 == '\0' - 1)
                return s1;
          }
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

int main() 
{
  const char * b = findFirst("Find me in this line", "me"); 
  cout << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: `*s2 == '\0' - 1`??? Are you trying to find out if `s2` is pointing to the last character before the null character?

Comment: @iTnewbie It is enough to use the standard C function strstr.

Comment: It looks like your questions was [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131175/recreate-the-strstr-function) before.

Comment: What is your *question* ? Whether this implementation will work? No, it won't; certainly not for all cases, and an interactive *debugger* will quickly expose why. Just watching what `s1` and `s2` point to as the loop progresses will be highly informative and I strongly advise you do so.

Answer (score 0):

This is basically re-doing the strstr function.

You can find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49131175/recreate-the-strstr-function).

Quoted from the linked question:

> The functionality is described as:
>
> strstr() function locates the ﬁrst occurrence in the string pointed to by s1 of the sequence of characters (excluding the terminating null character) in the string pointed to by s2.
>
> The strstr function returns a pointer to the located string, or a null pointer if the string is not found. If s2 points to a string with zero length, the function returns s1.

```
char *findFirst(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    const char *a;
    const char *b;

    b = s2;

    if (*b == 0) {
        return (char *) s1;
    }

    for ( ; *s1 != 0; s1 += 1) {
        if (*s1 != *b) {
            continue;
        }

        a = s1;
        while (1) {
            if (*b == 0) {
                return (char *) s1;
            }
            if (*a++ != *b++) {
                break;
            }
        }
        b = s2;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: what does it mean when you use: for( ; *s1 != 0; s1 += 1)

Comment: @iTnewbie It's a for loop. We go into each element of s1

Answer (score 0):

For starters you could use the standard C function `strstr` that does the task.

If you need to write a similar function yourself then it can be implemented in different ways. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

const char * findFirst( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    bool found = false;
    
    size_t n1 = std::strlen( s1 );
    size_t n2 = std::strlen( s2 );
    
    if ( !( n1 < n2 ) )
    {
        for ( const char *last = s1 + n1 - n2 + 1; !found && s1 != last;  )
        {
            size_t j = 0;
            
            while ( s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[j] ) ++j;
            
            if ( !( found = s2[j] == '\0' ) ) ++s1;
        }
    }

    return found ? s1 : nullptr; 
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << findFirst( "Find me in this line", "me" ) << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
me in this line
```

Instead of these statement within the for loop

```
size_t j = 0;

while ( s2[j] && s2[j] == s1[j] ) ++j;

if ( !( found = s2[j] == '\0' ) ) ++s1;
```

you could use the only statement

```
if ( !( found = memcmp( s1, s2, n2 ) == 0 ) ) ++s1;
```

If you are not allowed to use standard C string functions then the function `strlen` (that you should to rename as for example like `string_length`) can be implemented the following way

```
size_t string_length( const char *s )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while ( s[n] ) ++n;

    return n;
}
```

As for your function implementation then even the second statement

```
while (*s1)     // go through each element in s1
{
  ++s1;
  //...
```

makes the function wrong if for example the second string coincides with the beginning of the first string because you incremented the pointer `s1`.

Comment: My Prof. doesn't allow using any library member function like strlen(), strstr(), etc.

Comment: @iTnewbie You can write a function like strlen yourself.